# Problems calling SharePoint Document Library upload form with custom button

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-2016

I'm trying to create a link (not actually a button, but styled as a button) that calls up the Upload.aspx for a document library but I'm running into issues once Upload.aspx loads. The main issue is that the Cancel button is non-functional. I can upload select a file and upload it (and this works), but if I were to have accidentally clicked on the initial link and want to navigate away without uploading, the Cancel button doesn't make the page go away.

Now I haven't been able to have Upload.aspx display as a dialogue box over the list page--it gets called as a full page (even though I have "Open forms in dialog" enabled). I'm wondering if that's what the Cancel button expecting. Any ideas? The link that is being called is:

```
/mySite/_layouts/15/Upload.aspx?List=%7B4982C5B5%2DCF88%2D497F%2DA48D%2D815D7A355F0A%7D&amp;Source=https%3A%2F%2FmyServer%2Ecom%2FmySite%2FmyDocLibrary%2FForms%2FAllItems%2Easpx&amp;isdlg=1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was the `&isdlg=1` at the end of the URL that was causing the Cancel button to not work. I removed this from the URL and it works properly now.